esp-matter - How to build components and connectedhomeip
I am using the esp-matter repository and trying to add a new cluster server to the light example. This involves making changes to the internal components and connectedhomeip .
Calling :
idf.py build

from the light example folder doesn't build the components and connectedhomeip.
How to build everything?
